# XSD validation - Make child element as Mandatory if the Parent Element is Present, Else Make the Child Optional

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have an xml which looks like:

```
<RawData>
                  <EmailAddress>xyz.abc@email.com</EmailAddress>
                  <PassengerName>XYZ/ABC</PassengerName>
</RawData>
```

and the corresponding XSD like the below:

```
<xsd:element name="RawData" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="EmailAddress" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="PassengerName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
```

I need to make PassengerName Mandatory if RawData is present, else Optional.

Kindly help with your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As posed, your question doesn't make sense. PassengerName is a child of RawData and, thus, can't appear unless RawData is present. Perhaps you would like to rephrase the question.

Comment: Thanks Nic. I should have been more clear. RawData is a child tag for another parent tag, which makes RawData an Optional Tag. In case I make PassengerName as always Mandatory, then incase RawData is not present, it will always expect PassengerName. So the requirement is to bind PassengerName with RawData, so that when RawData is present, passengername is mandatory, otherwise optional.

Comment: Ah, so `PassengerName` can be a child of the parent of `RawData` when `RawData` is not present?

Comment: There was some confusion with the requirement. Things are clear now. As the parent Tag will always be associated with the child tag, I have made the child tag mandatory. Feeling was that in case the parent tag is missing, whether making the child as mandatory fail the xml. Well, thats not the case as the validation is happening only when the parent tag is present. That resolves the query. Thanks everyone for the valuable suggestions. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parent element is not present then it is not validated and the schema definitions for that element therefore have no relevance. If the parent is absent, the children will always be absent, and the schema automatically allows them to be absent.